# Is there a better approach to avoid or write less defensive code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

To avoid layout glitches between requests and loading = false/true, instead of showing null I like to provide some default data to UI. In my case, the response from API looks like code below:

```
  const {
    title = { value: "" },
    video_id = { value: "" },
    image = {
      value: []
    },
    type = { value: [{ codename: "" }] },
    sections = {
      value: [
        {
          title: { value: "" }
        }
      ]
    }
  } = (data && data[0]) || []
```

Because data is so nested I feel this is a bit cumbersome to write and wondering if there's a better approach.

Comment: The best ui experience is for you to have some kind of loader on the UI when the data is loading. Handling such a lot of nested data checks are quite cumbersome and error prone

Comment: You can either use loader or shimmer, I will prefer shimmer as it is current trend.

eg: https://codepen.io/kianlavi/pen/BzbRZw

Comment: More of an FYI, but [TypeScript 3.7 beta](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7-beta/) includes *optional chaining* meaning that you can do something like: `console.log(data[0]?.sections?.value?.[0]?.title?.value)`